# UITableView methods not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a simple table view controller with a UITableView control. I have implemented UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource in my header file. I have assigned the data source and delegate to be the ViewController that contains the UITableView. However, none of the table view methods are firing. I have posted stripped down source code and a screen shot showing the the delegate/datasource. What could be the possible cause of why the events aren't getting wired?

(gauges is a model that contains an NSArray of value objects)

Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GaugeList.h"

@interface SitePickerViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) GaugeList *gauges;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "SitePickerViewController.h"

@interface SitePickerViewController ()

@end

@implementation SitePickerViewController
@synthesize gauges;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSInteger rowCount = [gauges.gaugeList count];
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection called: %i\n", rowCount);
    return rowCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath\n");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    return cell;
}

-(void)loadView{
    gauges = [[GaugeList alloc] initWithStateIdentifier:@"WV" andType:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad called: %i\n", [gauges.gaugeList count]);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: did you hooked correctly?

Comment: Seems like there is some problem with the hooking of delegate and datasource functions

Comment: *GaugeList is an NSArray of value objects*. You subclassed NSArray? Why did u do so? did it hurt?

Comment: *I am using storyboard and have mapped the tableview datasource and delegate to the ViewController. I tried to post the image of that but since I'm new here I wasn't allowed.* add a link to the image, I will add it as image

Comment: did you specify the correct view controller class for the scene in IB?

Comment: If you think everything is hooked up correctly... always try to do a full build clean (including cleaning your build folder). I have moved away from storyboards and XIBs for the reason and now only hook up UIs programmatically.

Comment: do u use static cells?

Comment: Sorry, i should rephrase one of my last comments. Gaugelist is a model that contains an NSArray of value objects

Comment: You should alter your question with all this information.

Comment: Do not override `loadView` unless your implementation actually creates a view and assigns it to `self.view`. Your current implementation of `loadView` is preventing any view from being created. Move the `gauges = ...` line to `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks maddy, overriding the loadView method seems to be the issue. Can you post this as an answer to my issue?

Comment: @FirecrackerFred Done. Please note, that when you reply to someone, put an `@` symbol before their actual username. I never saw your comment until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your implementation of `loadView`. Any implementation of `loadView` must actually create the main view for the controller and assign it to `self.view`. As you have it, no view ends up being created for your view controller.

Move the method call that you have to `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    gauges = [[GaugeList alloc] initWithStateIdentifier:@"WV" andType:nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad called: %i\n", [gauges.gaugeList count]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad

set

`tableView.delegate = self;`

And also allocate the tableView if you are not using XIB. Or if u t using xib map the delegates and data source to files owner

Comment: Also set `tableView.dataSource = self;`

Comment: I am using storyboard and have mapped the tableview datasource and delegate to the ViewController. I tried to post the image of that but since I'm new here I wasn't allowed. Do I need to also set up the tableview to be an outlet?

Comment: add a link to the image, I will add it as image

Answer (score 0):

Making the SitePickerViewController a delegate and datasource isn't quite enough. You also have to set that class as the datasource and delegate. Make sure to hook up to that IBOutlet as well.

```
@interface <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *functionTableView;
@end

@implementation
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.functionTableView.delegate = self;
    self.functionTableView.dataSource = self;
}

//Delegate and datasource methods down here
@end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but still the only method to be called is viewDidLoad

Comment: I also tried placing this in the loadView method, which is getting called before viewDidLoad. However, results are the same.

Comment: There is no way this should not work. Probably you have an error somewhere else.

Comment: Did you map control drag the table view to hook it up to the IBOutlet from the storyboard, I didn't hook up the data source and delegate for the table view in the storyboard, and opted to do it manually instead, as shown above.